# Erro no extrator de expressão regular - JMETER

Tags: regex, jmeter

Boa tarde pessoal,

Não estou conseguindo extrair um dado retornado no parâmetro do retorno da chamada no serviço GET HTTP - JMETER. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Segue abaixo:

**JSON retornado na chamada:**

```
{
  "wallets" : [ {
    "id" : "eyJpZGVudGl0eSI6WzQ4LDQyLDQ4LDUsNiwzLDQzLDEwMSwxMTIsMywzMywwLC0zMCw4MSwxMDQsMCw2NywtMTcsNDcsLTM0LC0yNiwtNDksLTg0LDkxLC0xMDgsMTcsMjUsMTksLTcxLC0xMTcsLTEwMywzNSwtMjEsNDAsLTcyLDY3LDEwNSwxMCwtNDAsMTE3LC0xMTEsLTEwLDExNiwtNThdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMC4xLjEifQ=="
  } ]
}
```

**Necessito obter o dado do "id".**

Já tentei diversas maneiras, mas sem sucesso!

Aguardo e obrigado desde já!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primeira opção**

Segue regex que irá retornar a info sobre o id:

```
id"\s*:\s*"([\w=]*)"
```

Passos para funcionar:

- Use essa expressão no campo **Regular Expression**
- Coloque o valor 1 no campo **Match No.**
- No campo **Field To Check** selecione a opção *Body*

[Segue link com o teste da Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Nbtxr3/1)

---

**Segunda opção**

Siga esses passos para funcionar:

- Preencha o campo Reference com o seguinte PATH `wallets[0].id`
- Preencha o campo Regular Expression com a seguinte Regex `(.+?)`
- Coloque o valor 1 no campo **Match No.**